# .UI converted to .Py falls in PyInstaller application

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, pyinstaller

I try to release python application, that uses Qt gui. To deploy app in fast and python-free way i used Pyinstaller
I converted my UI to py.

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

```
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(362, 669)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(1)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(1)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.centralwidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.centralwidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    self.centralwidget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 361, 671))
    self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
    self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
    self.verticalLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetMaximumSize)
    self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(2, 2, 2, 2)
    self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
    self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
    self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
    self.pshBtnSetInput = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
    self.pshBtnSetInput.setObjectName("pshBtnSetInput")
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pshBtnSetInput)
    self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
    self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
    self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
    self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
    self.pshBtnSetOutput = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
    self.pshBtnSetOutput.setObjectName("pshBtnSetOutput")
    self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pshBtnSetOutput)
    self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
    self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
    self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2)
    self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
    self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)
    self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
    self.pshBtnAddAttributes = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
    self.pshBtnAddAttributes.setObjectName("pshBtnAddAttributes")
    self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.pshBtnAddAttributes)
    self.pshBtnDelAttribute = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
    self.pshBtnDelAttribute.setObjectName("pshBtnDelAttribute")
    self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.pshBtnDelAttribute)
    self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3)
    self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
    self.tableView.setObjectName("tableView")
    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tableView)
    self.pshBtnCut = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
    self.pshBtnCut.setObjectName("pshBtnCut")
    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pshBtnCut)
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.actionOpen = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.actionOpen.setObjectName("actionOpen")

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Нарезка тайлов"))
    self.pshBtnSetInput.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Входящие"))
    self.pshBtnSetOutput.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Исходящие"))
    self.pshBtnAddAttributes.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить атрибут"))
    self.pshBtnDelAttribute.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Удалить атрибут"))
    self.pshBtnCut.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Нарезать"))
    self.actionOpen.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open Folder"))
```

It all works fine in interpreter, it works fine when executed from .py or when i test from spyder. I frozed it with pyinstaller, and it works.
But when i deploy it on any win7 x86 machines it stops working first time i call ui class.

I traced error to call of any member of this class inside the constructor of MainWindow.

```
class MainForm(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
"""
Main Form of RasterCutterForm
"""
def __init__(self, parent = None):
    try:
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.DataModel = None
        self.DataModel = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(parent = self)
        self.DataModel.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Атрибут", "Значение"])
        print("self.tableView.setModel(self.DataModel)")
        self.ui.tableView.setModel(self.DataModel)
        print("Init Done.")
    except Exception as exc:
        print(exc)
```

Last print( " Set Model " ) is the last executed command.
Any ideas?

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: Windows shows "Stopped working". No additional information.
I looked into the build logs. PyQt5.sip is missing. And module containing MainForm and UI_MainWindow called invalid. I'll try to research that, but funny thing. This error only occurs on win7 machines.

Comment: strange, do you have the most recent versions of pyinstaller and all your modules?